# Hallel in syngagogue on Pesach night before dark

Tags: halacha, passover, passover-seder-hagada, synagogue, hallel

[Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 487:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.487.4?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&vhe=Maginei_Eretz:_Shulchan_Aruch_Orach_Chaim,_Lemberg,_1893&lang=bi) describes a custom to recite Hallel in the synagogue at the end of Arvit on the first (two) night(s) of Pesach.

Some (e.g. [Gra](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Beur_HaGra_on_Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.487.4.2)) link this custom to the practice found in [Tosefta Pesachim 10:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tosefta_Pesachim.10.5?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&vhe=Tosefta_Pesachim&lang=bi). The Tosefta records that those unable to recite Hallel themselves as part of the Seder, go to the synagogue and hear it read there.

Given that Shulchan [Aruch Orach Chaim 472:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.472.1?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&vhe=Maginei_Eretz:_Shulchan_Aruch_Orach_Chaim,_Lemberg,_1893&lang=bi) rules that the Seder must only start at nightfall, would the same apply to Hallel in the synagogue? That is, may a congregation praying Arvit before nightfall recite Hallel?

(I'm interested in all answers to this question, whether or not they take into account the Tosefta as a / the reason for the custom of reciting Hallel in the synagogue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Sefer הסדר בערוך, פרק כ"ח סעיף ט and in the associated footnotes two opinions are brought.

1. Haggodas Moadim Uzmanim- that hallel in shul is part of the mitzvos whose חיוב is at night and for such the general rule of tosefes Yom tov does not help to allow it to be said earlier.
2. The Shulchan Aruch's ambiguity leads one to believe that there is no reason not to be allowed to say it early. But even more so is it clear in the [Meiri Pesachim 117b](https://www.sefaria.org/Meiri_on_Pesachim.117b?vhe=Meiri_on_Shas&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that Hallel can be said by day. The reason being that it is a זכר for the Hallel said during עבודת קרבן פסח which was said by day on erev pessach.